# Determining the equilibrium points.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

\begin{equation}
\frac{du(t)}{dt}=au(t)v(t)-bu(t)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{dv(t)}{dt}=-au(t)v(t)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{dw(t)}{dt}=u(t)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
u(t)+v(t)+w(t)=1
\end{equation}

I have to determine the equilibrium points of these equations. I started of with $\frac{du(t)}{dt}=\frac{dv(t)}{dt}=\frac{dw(t)}{dt}=0$. It follows from the third equation that $u(t)=0$. But then I get stuck. I would say that $v(t)$ and $w(t)$ can have every value, because u(t) has to be equal to zero, but I don't think that's right.

Comment: The condition $u(t)+v(t)+w(t)=1$ is very odd since it imposes $(1-b)u(t)=0$ for every $t$.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty much correct! Just note that since $\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{dw}{dt} = 0$, it follows that $v(t)$ and $w(t)$ are constant functions which satisfy $v(t) + w(t) = 1$. Any choice of such functions works since they will satisfy all of your given equations.